# Can't display the contents of a CSV

Tags: java, r, csv

When I am trying to display the contents of a CSV file by integrating R with java, I get the following output:

```
org.rosuda.REngine.REXPGenericVector@2f8c5b4f+[1]named
```

My code is

```
REXP x;  
x= c.eval("elements<-read.csv(file ='D:/Book2.csv', head=TRUE, sep=',')");
System.out.println(x);
```

`asString()` is not helping to change the output. I want the program to display the contents of the  CSV file in readable format. What do I do?

Comment: try replacing `head=TRUE` with `header=TRUE`

Comment: And also D:/Book2.csv with D:\\Book2.csv if you're using windows, which I think you are.

Comment: The problem is not with accessing the CSV file. The program is able to do it. Just that the output is not readable.